# nopCommerce - Is it Code First?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I recently started digging into nopCommerce and from their blog I found out that It's a Code First approch development. But, I have found following files in the nopCommerece sample.

1. Data.NopModel.csdl
2. Data.NopModel.ssdl
3. Data.NopModel.msl

I want to know how does SSDL/MSL/CSDL files are created? I know these are from entiry framework. But while code-first development how does it got generated?

I want to know from where the meta data file generated?

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm unable to find those files neither on the legacy 1.x nor on the 2.x rewrite.

Comment: Hi M.Ang, I am using the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code First generates the XML in these files internally but never writes them to disk. In a normal Code First project you would not have these files but sometimes looking at their contents can be useful for debugging.

If you want to get these files from Code First then you can use `EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx()`. The EDMX XML that this method creates contains threww sections--one for the conceptual model (CSDL), one for the store model (SSDL) and one for the mapping between the two (MSL).

Comment: Hello Arthur, Thanks for the information. So you mean to say that nopCommerce used EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx()???

Comment: No idea. I was answering how you can use Code First and get those files.